# Authenticating Node / Socket.io app with existing token and API

Tags: node.js, authentication, socket.io, api-key

So I have an app I am building (using Steroids / appgyver, although not really relevant), with some real time elements (chat rooms, private messages, etc) which will utilise socket.io. The app itself is behind a login, using an existing http API that stores a token locally for the rest of the app requests.

I want to authenticate the socket.io bits using the same API, and token as the rest of the app. I have gone through hundreds of articles this morning covering these topics, but none seem to do exactly what I want, and seem overly complicated. They all seem to route the auth locally, or require username and password inputs, which I have already resolved and a token provided instead.

When a user connects to the server...

`io.on('connection', function(socket){`

...or when the server receives a message from the users client...

`socket.on('message', function(msg){`

I want it to ensure only authenticated users can do this by sending the token. I have had a bit of a look at http://passportjs.org but can't see a strategy that works with tokens and API's over http.

**So how can I authenticate my socket.io app with my existing RESTful API and locally stored token?**